# .sh file execution: permission denied exit code 126

Tags: permissions, docker

i got an issue when running the Dockfile:
here are the codes:

```
COPY UpdateServer/FT.Ubuntu*x64*.sh /root/app/
# Where we are going to place the files we need
WORKDIR /root/app
# Execute the setup
RUN ./$(find FT.Ubuntu*x64*.sh) -s
```

and then got error `RUN ./$(find FT.Ubuntu*x64*.sh) -s`

```
exit code:126
```

i have tried so many ways,but couldn't figure out. not sure what is wrong with it

Answer (score 2):

The [bash manual](https://manpages.org/bash) explains it:

> If a command is not found, the child process created to execute it returns a status of 127. If a command is found but is not executable, the return status is 126.

You did not make `FT.Ubuntux64.sh` executable.

> `/root/app/`

Who decided to use `/root` to install software? Please do not. Use a dedicated mountpoint or `/opt/` for that.

> `./$(find FT.Ubuntux64.sh) -s`

Just no. From you method just do

```
chmod 750 /root/app/FT.Ubuntux64.sh
./root/app/FT.Ubuntux64.sh -s
```

If you do that without chmod you would get a normal error notice about it not being executable.